# GWT FlexTable Header Column

Tags: css, gwt

I have CSS definitions for various elements around Table as shown below (Details omitted, only style names for reference).

```
table.entities {
border: 1px solid #c5d7ef;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

table.entities th, table.entities td {
padding: .25em 1.5em .5em .5em;
}
table.entities th {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  background: #e5ecf9;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.entities th a, table.entities th a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

table.entities td {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.entities tr.even td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

And I apply the styles for even rows like:

```
flexTable.getRowFormatter().getElement(row).setClassName("even");
```

But for some reason, the header styles are not applied to table. Here is what I have tried

- As it is I would expect `th` to apply style to first row, but not sure if that is a valid assumption to make
- Changed the header style from `th` to something like `theader` and then explicitely applied to first row using row formatter for first row. I tried first row value as 1 & 0 both but either didn't give me results

Can anyone help me spotting where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the FlexTable does not render `<th>` tags. Everything is contained in the `<tbody>`.

You must also remember that the `<tr>` tag is pretty much unstylable so to style the whole row you need to apply the same style to all child `<td>` tags.

```
tr.someStyle td {
  /* all styles that apply to the row */
}
```

If you post your actual styles and what is not being applied, maybe we can help further.

Comment: Added style details to original question

Comment: @vishal.biyani, ok did you also read the part about FlexTable, not rendering `<th>` tags? I just double checked the source code of the FlexTable, everything is a `<td>`. So you need a special style for the first row.

Comment: You are right about the <th>. I created a separate style for header and applied using flexTable.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(0, "headerRow"); The earlier mistake included wrong row number and way of applying style. Thanks for your help, you lead me to right solution!